# In Scrapy how to seperate items in output json file

Tags: json, scrapy

I am a new learner of Scrapy and encounter a problem. I get several json responses when crawling websites(that part I have already done). I want to fill them in items and then output to one json file. But the output file is not what I expected.

The item class looks like this:

```
class USLPlayer(scrapy.Item): 
  ln = scrapy.Field() 
  fn = scrapy.Field() ...
```

The original json file structure looks like this:

```
{"players":{"4752569":{"ln":"Musa","fn":"Yahaya", .... ,"apprvd":"59750"}, "4801435":{"ln":"Ackley","fn":"Brian", ... ,"apprvd":"59750"}, ...}}
```

The expected result I hope to be looks like this:

```
{"item" :{"ln":"Musa","fn":"Yahaya", .... ,"apprvd":"59750"}},{"item": {"ln":"Ackley","fn":"Brian", ... ,"apprvd":"59750"}, ...
```

Basically I hope every item should be separated list.

The code about fill item is:

```
players = json.loads(plain_text)
    for id, player in players["players"].items(): 
         for key, value in player.items():
              item = USLPlayer() item[key] = value 
                    yield item
```

Is there any way I can ouput json file as I expected. Thank you very much for kind answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [JSON lines feed exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-format-jsonlines)?

It will output your items as JSON objects one per line. Then, reading the list of players from the file is as easy as using `json.loads` on each line.